# Post form data params using Retrofit kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Am new to retrofit and I would like to post form data using retrofit and coroutines in kotlin.

[image]

```
    val api = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
      

    val formData = listOf(
        "function" to "getSubscriber" ,
        "phoneNumber" to "0100844789")

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        
    }
```

how do I proceed from here

Comment: you need a function for your retrofit we call it service function which you don't have here , Since you want to use   coroutines scope you might want to suspend the service function

Comment: also since you are using JSON converter factory for your retrofit you might want also to send a JSON as a string instead of two parameters, class model is needed too! to make things simple

Answer (score 1):

***Some of The references is below I think it helps you***

[Article Link](https://medium.com/swlh/simplest-post-request-on-android-kotlin-using-retrofit-e0a9db81f11a)

[Video tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok697I1j1aE)

Comment: Please mark the as accepted answer so it is easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

So I have done what @Providerz has said and it has worked.

```
 val api = Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .build()
      .create(MyAPI::class.java)

     lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val response = api.getSubscriber("getSubscriber","0100844789")
      Log.d("######", response.message.toString()) 
     }
```

MyAPI

```
    interface MyAPI {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php")
    suspend fun getSubscriber(@Field("function") function: String, @Field("phoneNumber") phoneNumber: String): Json4Kotlin_Base
}
```